# Sharepoint 2010- List items got deleted automatically

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am facing an issue with List items got deleted automatically. what are the possible reasons behind this deletion. The existing list items were deleted.

Regards,
user4768610

Comment: This question got nothing to do with programing and is best suited for http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

1) Check Information Management Policy Settings for your list (more information here [Link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/manjesh/archive/2010/01/10/how-to-configure-document-expiration-policy.aspx), [link](http://www.boostsolutions.com/blog/manage-information-management-policy-settings-in-sharepoint-2010-document-library/))

2) It can be custom solution (for example workflow)

3) If your list is task list, reason can be in Workflow Auto Cleanup timer job. This job will permanently delete workflow instances and related task entries that still exist 60 days after a workflow is completed or canceled.

4) Try find items in Recycle Bin and check who deleted it